# How to store image submitted as a variable (dropzone JS)

Tags: dropzone

I need to build a confirm button for the images being dropped in Dropzone, which, on press will store the image in a variable and then move on. What function do I call to get this image?

I currently only have this set up:

```html
<div id=dropzone >
  <form action="/file-upload" class="dropzone">
    <div class="fallback">
      <input name="file" type="file" multiple />
    </div>
  </form>
  <img id=confirmbtn src="/images/confirm.png" alt="Confirm">
  <img id=cancelbtn src="/images/cancel.png" alt="Click me to remove the file." data-dz-remove />
   </div>
```

I am looking to store the image as a string

Answer (score 0):

I did a ctrl+f (data-dz-thumbnail) on dropzone.js and found this in the preview:

```html
<-this is ONE LINE BTW->
previewTemplate: "<div class=\"dz-preview dz-file-preview\">\n 
 <div class=\"dz-image\">
<img id='data-dz-thumbnail'data-dz-thumbnail />
</div>\n  <div class=\"dz-details\">\n 
   <div class=\"dz-size\"><span data-dz-size></span></div>\n 
   <div class=\"dz-filename\"><span data-dz-name></span></div>\n 
 </div>\n 
 <div class=\"dz-progress\"><span class=\"dz-upload\" data-dz-uploadprogress></span></div>\n
 </div>",
```

I then changed the whole image thumbnail element to this:

```html
<img id='data-dz-thumbnail'data-dz-thumbnail />
//I added the id='data-dz-thumbnail' part
```

Then i added an event listener to js

```js
something.onclick....{
var image=document.getElementById('data-dz-thumbnail').src
}
```

And that is literally it